# Jquery Autocomplete plugin with Django (Trey Piepmeier solution)

Tags: javascript, html, django, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

So, I'm basing my code on Trey's solution on:
http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/12/10/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-django/

The script is:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
        $('#id_members').autocomplete('{{ object.get_absolute_url }}members/lookup', {
            dataType: 'json',
            width: 200,
            parse: function(data) {
                return $.map(data, function(row) {
                    return { data:row, value:row[1], result:row[0] };
                });
            }
            }).result(
                function(e, data, value) {
                    $("#id_members_pk").val(value);
                }
            );
        }
    );
   </script>
```

The views.py:

```
def members_lookup(request, pid):  
    results = []
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET.has_key(u'q'):
            value = request.GET[u'q']
            # Ignore queries shorter than length 1
            if len(value) > 2:

                model_results = Member.objects.filter(
                                Q(user__first_name__icontains=value) | Q(user__last_name__icontains=value)
                                )
                results = [ (x.user.get_full_name(), x.id) for x in model_results ]
    json = simplejson.dumps(results)
    print json
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

**The problem** is:
It stops refining the search results after the initial lookup.
For example:
If I set len(value) > 2, after I type the 3rd character it will give me a list of suggestions. But if I keep on typing the 4th or 5th character, the list of suggestions doesn't change.

Any suggestions on why this is?

Comment: Is the problem server-side or client-side?  If it is server-side, do you get the same results when you run the queries in `./manage.py shell`?  Are you entering in characters that will result in different results with the 4th and 5th characters?

Comment: The problem is client side. Especially the parse portion of the code. I noticed (using Firebug) that when I got rid of the offending code, it hits the database for each typed character like it's supposed to, but it doesn't parse the response...

Yes, the 4th and 5th character is supposed to narrow the result list further.

Answer (score 0):

For server side I recommend you take a look an [ajax selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/) application

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing a string from the view side in the format that jquery autocomplete can parse easier.

```
def members_lookup(request, pid):
    results = ''
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET.has_key(u'q'):
            value = request.GET[u'q']
            # Ignore queries shorter than length 1
            if len(value) > 2:
                model_results = Member.objects.filter(
                                Q(user__first_name__icontains=value) | Q(user__last_name__icontains=value)
                               )
                for r in model_results:
                    results += '%s|%s\n' % (r.user.get_full_name(), r.id)

    return HttpResponse(results, mimetype='text/html')
```

Then on the client side:

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
    $("#id_members").autocomplete("{{ object.get_absolute_url }}members/lookup/", {
        width: 260,
        minChars: 2,
        selectFirst: false
    });

    $("#id_members").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        if (data)
            $(this).parent().next().find("input").val(data[1]);
    });
});
</script>
```